# a romantic escape place or a romantic place

Tags: word-meaning

> The writers think that the moon is a place for a romantic escape.

If I change this sentence,

> The writers think that the moon is a romantic escape *place*.

In this sentence, I wanted to know the word "place" is redundant or not.

Answer (score 1):

It would be redundant.

In the first sentence, the word escape is used in reference to the action of escaping.

In the second sentence, the word escape is used in reference to the place one escapes to, and therefore replaces the word "place."